# Magento 2: Can you use a Plugin with the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` type?

Tags: php, magento2, plugin, psr-logger

I've got a di.xml that looks something like this

```
<config>
<type name="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface">                
    <plugin name="namespace_modulename_plugins_psr"
            type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugins\Psr"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>     
</type>
</config>
```

The `Namespace\Modulename\Plugins\Psr` class can be instantiated, and has a `beforeInfo` method defined

```
public function beforeInfo($subject)
{
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    exit;
}
```

However, if I inject a logger and try to use it

```
/* @var $psr `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` */
$psr->info("This is a message");
```

The message will successfully log, but the system does not call my plugin method.

Is there something special about the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` that makes in non-plugin-able?  If not, does anyone have a solid methodology for debugging plugin configuration issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of research, it turns out the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` (and its underlying concrete `Monolog` implementation class) **can** be plugged into.  The problem was, if you have developer mode enabled you need to do a full di compile ([see this bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2674)). Running

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

should get the interceptors generated, and the plugins working.

Answer (score 3):

`PSR\Log\LoggerInterface` is not in magento module or framework folder. So it's not analyzed by compiler and will not be pluginized in production mode. If you want to pluginize/configure behavior of third-party classes, you should use adapter.

Comment: +1 for useful information, but I'm not sure I follow that -- are you saying the plugin system only works with Magento namespaced classes?  Does that means that third party modules are also not plugin-able?  Also, if it's the compiler that control this wouldn't that mean when running in developer mode the plugin would be applied?  Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by compiler?

Comment: Expressed myself incorrectly. Compiler collects configuration from module libraries (both magento & 3rd-party), magento framework and generation directories. Interception subsystem works differently in dev mode & in production. In dev mode it tries to read configuration for classes in runtime. For production it reads configuration from files prepared by compiler. So compiler dictates for which files the configuration is available. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  One last follow up -- based on the behavior I'm seeing it seems like non-production modes also know to skip code that's not part of the module library.  Any idea where this skipping happens? (at configuration loading time, instantiation time, etc.)

Comment: Re: "PSR\Log\LoggerInterface is not in magento module or framework folder. So it's not analyzed by compiler "  This is incorrect/incomplete.  The `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`, if used as a type hint in a Magento classe (which it is) IS analyzed by the compiler. The problem was/is it's an early stage object, and in developer mode its instantiated before the di config is loaded, and then that version is cached in the object manager. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2674

Comment: Was a surprise for me. I expected that compiled definition would not process unknown type but it's only for arguments. Thanks for investigating correct answer.